# MongoDB find key by value in nested array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

My mongodb Document is

```
    {
        _id:'ghuvt6GYrs6Hhgts6uhg',
        photos:[
            {
                "photoId":"1322",
                "title":"Life is beautiful",
                "score":"1331322"
            },
            {
                "photoId":"1323",
                "title":"Very Cute Dog",
                "score":"1231726"
            },
            {
                "photoId":"1324",
                "title":"Funny Cat",
                "score":"1246556"
            },
            {
                ...
                ...
                ...
            }
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
        ]
    }
```

What I want to achieve is, get sub-array inside `photos` array where `photoId:"1323"`
    I can achieve it in php with

```
$doc_test = $collection_images->findone(
        array("_id" => new MongoId('ghuvt6GYrs6Hhgts6uhg')),
        array("photos" => 
            array(
                '$elemMatch' => array(
                    "photoId" => "1323"
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

And by result will look like [JSON]

```
   {
                "photoId":"1323",
                "title":"Very Cute Dog",
                "score":"1231726"
            }
```

But I want key (index) value of the matched sub-array, as it would be `1` because that sub-array is second from the top in `photos` array

Please suggest a solution without using map-reduce

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without some client-side logic or a small change to your data. The shortest path to victory is to retrieve the document by "_id":

```
> var doc = db.images.findOne({ "_id" : "ghuvt6GYrs6Hhgts6uhg" })
```

and then scan the array for `photoId` to get the index of "1323"

```
> var spot = -1
> for (var i = 0; i < doc.photos.length; i++) { if (doc.photos[i].photoId === "1323") spot = i }
```

You can also just tag the array documents with their position:

```
{
    _id:'ghuvt6GYrs6Hhgts6uhg',
    photos:[
        {
            "spot" : 0,
            "photoId":"1322",
            "title":"Life is beautiful",
            "score":"1331322"
        },
        {
            "spot" : 1,
            "photoId":"1323",
            "title":"Very Cute Dog",
            "score":"1231726"
        },
        ...
```

Why are you looking for the index of the photo in the array? Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish the same thing.